# Same vector graphics but different SVG output in CorelDRAW and Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, corel-draw

I had draw an ellipse in corel and illustrator and export as SVG. when i open their code, it was major difference in those two files.

Look at below ellipse SVG code

[image: SVG Code]

I think Illustrator looks clean. any chance to make corel SVG like this?

Comment: And why exactly is tgis an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a simple SVG like that could be stripped back even further. So, the Adobe Illustrator SVG isn't as "clean" as it could be.

For example, this one was made in Inkscape 1.0, saving as Optimised SVG, first removing all transforms and unnecessary attributes in the built in XML editor, and then optimising when saving by removing tags such as metadata and xml space, and unnecessary groups.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="98mm" height="58.7mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 98 58.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<ellipse cx="49" cy="29.3" rx="48.7" ry="29" fill="#4d4d4d" stroke="#2ca02c" stroke-width=".6"/>
</svg>
```

To answer your question more directly, there is nothing to stop you from manually editing the SVG. Also, different software has different approaches and tweaks you can apply to SVG output. Check the [CorelDraw documentation](http://product.corel.com/help/CorelDRAW/540227992/Main/EN/Documentation/CorelDRAW-Scalable-Vector-Graphics-SVG.html#4435384) to see what options are possible. Personally, I think it's probably a bit much to expect different applications to output exactly the same SVG.

Just as a side note, since Inksape is free, there's no reason you couldn't also use it to optimize your SVGs if you prefer to use a GUI instead of manually editing the SVG in a text editor.

Comment: Also it is not impossible to write your own svg exporter either. I have done it you can even find one example on GD.SE if you care to look.