# How to export from Inkscape w/o transforms

Tags: inkscape, transform

I have created SVG image and I would like to display it on the HTML page. I want to use only `path` elements with `d` attributes. To this end I need to export it somehow without transforms, namely, I want to have absolute values in `d` attribute. How to do this?

Comment: Although not a duplicate question, I posted [an answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138798/89608) which describes how to do it in Inkscape.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried different checkboxes for optimized SVG but neither of them helped to remove transform.

Comment: You didn't read the answer. It says to remove the transforms in the XML editor, then export as optimized SVG.

Comment: @BillyKerr OK, it just removed transform and now my drawing is misplaced.

Comment: Well, yes since you removed the transform, that's what will happen. You can select your drawing and do Shift+Ctrl+R (Resize page to selection).

Comment: @BillyKerr this what I was doing because I'm trying to export icon, but transform is still there.

Comment: Maybe consider sharing the SVG on svgshare.com - can't promise anything but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I found it at Stack Overflow.

- Select the group that contains all those transforms you want to get
  rid off,
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (ungroup),
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (group again).

It works! Instead of Apply Transforms extension.